# How to give an image input to my OpenCV code?

Tags: pi-3, raspicam

I am doing OpenCV on my RPi 3b for my project on Controlled Environmental Agriculture. I completed all the coding part of the OpenCV and also wrote a code for my RPi NOIR camera to capture images and store it on the desktop. How do I give this image as my input to the OpenCV code? I am going to capture just one image of the plant per day.

Comment: Is your question "how can I pass a filename to Python code?", or something else? (Please consider editing your question and removing any irrelevant details; it will make it clearer what you are asking and hence improve the chance of useful replies.)

Comment: There's nothing in this question that is intrinsic to the Pi -- that's simply where you got the data, which is now in a standardized form (an image file).  General programming questions belong on our larger parent site, [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/), which has over 50000 questions tagged `opencv` (about twice our total of *all* questions).